# Type 'File | null' is not assignable to type 'File'. in angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

Hi I am new to Angular and currently I am working with Angular 11 project and there I have to upload a CSV file and extract the records of the file in client side and save them in the database via ASP.NET Web API.

Here I followed a tutorial and tried to get the data of the CSV file in angular side and display them in the same page.

Then I got this error,

Type 'File | null' is not assignable to type 'File'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'File'.ts(2322)

I tried so many things but still couldn't solve this. Could you please help me?

**This is my .ts file,**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  lines: any = [];
  linesR: any = [];

  changeListener(files: FileList) {
    console.log(files);
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      let file: File = files.item(0);
      console.log(file.name);
      console.log(file.size);
      console.log(file.type);

      let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(file);
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        let csv: any = reader.result;
        let allTextLines = [];
        allTextLines = csv.split(/\r|\n|\r/);

        let headers = allTextLines[0].split(';');
        let data = headers;
        let tarr = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
          tarr.push(data[j]);
        }
        this.lines.push(tarr);
        let tarrR = [];
        let arrl = allTextLines.length;
        let rows = [];
        for (let i = 1; i < arrl; i++) {
          rows.push(allTextLines[i].split(';'));
        }
        for (let j = 0; j < arrl; j++) {
          tarrR.push(rows[j]);
        }
        this.linesR.push(tarrR);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**This is my .html file**

```
    <div class="container">
    <h1 style="text-align: center"> File Upload </h1>
    <br><br>

    <input class="form-control" type="file" class="upload" (change)="changeListener($event.target.files)">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let item of lines[0]; let i = index">
                    {{item}}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of linesR[0]; let i = index">
                <td *ngFor="let itemm of lines[0]; let j = index">
                    {{item[j]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[This is the error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os6GZ.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Change your method like following changeListener(files: File[]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Using:

**fileupload.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from "@angular/core";
    
@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
      name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
    
      lines: any = [];
      linesR: any = [];
    
      ngOnInit() {}
    
      changeListener(files) {
        let fileList = (<HTMLInputElement>files.target).files;
        if (fileList && fileList.length > 0) {
          let file: File = fileList[0];
          console.log(file.name);
          console.log(file.size);
          console.log(file.type);
    
          let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsText(file);
          reader.onload = e => {
            let csv: any = reader.result;
            let allTextLines = [];
            allTextLines = csv.split(/\r|\n|\r/);
    
            let headers = allTextLines[0].split(";");
            let data = headers;
            let tarr = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
              tarr.push(data[j]);
            }
            this.lines.push(tarr);
            let tarrR = [];
            let arrl = allTextLines.length;
            let rows = [];
            for (let i = 1; i < arrl; i++) {
              rows.push(allTextLines[i].split(";"));
            }
            for (let j = 0; j < arrl; j++) {
              tarrR.push(rows[j]);
            }
            this.linesR.push(tarrR);
          };
        }
      }
    }
```

**fileupload.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 style="text-align: center">File Upload</h1>
  <br /><br />

  <input
    class="form-control"
    type="file"
    class="upload"
    (change)="changeListener($event)"
  />

  <table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let item of lines[0]; let i = index">
          {{item}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of linesR[0]; let i = index">
        <td *ngFor="let itemm of lines[0]; let j = index">
          {{item[j]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Msk, thank you so much. I tried your answer like this, 

`changeListener(files: File[]) {
   // const file: File | undefined = files?.item(0);
    console.log(files);
    console.log(files[0]);
    var file: File = files[0];
    //if (file && files.length > 0) {
      if (files && files.length > 0) {
      let file: File = files.item(0);
      console.log(file.name);
      console.log(file.size);
      console.log(file.type);`

and now I am getting this error,

**Property 'item' does not exist on type 'File[]'. let file: File = files.item(0);**

Could you please help me?

Comment: you can get the file with files[0]

Comment: I have updated the answer .get the file from files array as follows let file: File = files[0]; not use files.item(0)

Comment: Hi I tried your answer. Now I am getting errors in .html file like this,

 `Object is possibly 'null'. <input class="form-control" type="file" class="upload" (change)="changeListener($event.target.files)">`

`Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. <input class="form-control" type="file" class="upload" (change)="changeListener($event.target.files)">`

Comment: try this stackblitz example, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I have implemented you code on the stackblitz it's working now. you can check in the following stackblitz url:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bmzpqj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is like -

```
let file: File | any = null;
```

OR

```
let file: File | null = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `strict: true` with typescript. That's good! The issue you are facing though is that this piece:

```
let file: File = files.item(0);
```

can return undefined, even though you check for the length before. This would make the type `File | null` , but you are stating it should just be `File`.

Better would be to change it to the following:

```
changeListener(files: FileList) {
 const file: File | null = files?.item(0);

 if (file) {
   // here `file` will have type `File` because it has been asserted with the `if`
      console.log(file.size);
      console.log(file.type);

      let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(file);
      reader.onload = (e) => {
  //...
```

Comment: Hi Poul thank you so much. I tried your answer like this,

`changeListener(files: FileList) {
    const file: File | undefined = files?.item(0);
    console.log(files);
    if (file && files.length > 0) {
      //if (files && files.length > 0) {
      //let file: File = files.item(0);
      console.log(file.name);
      console.log(file.size);
      console.log(file.type);`

and now I am getting this error.

**Type 'File | null' is not assignable to type 'File | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'File | undefined'.ts(2322)**

Could you please help me?

Comment: @kalpana Correct, if `item` does not exist, it will return `null` instead of undefined. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about that you will have values into files item then you can say :

```
let file: File = files.item(0) as File;
```

Comment: Hi thanks I tried it and now it is giving this error,

`error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. <input class="form-control" type="file" class="upload" (change)="changeListener($event.target.files)">`

`error TS2339: Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. <input class="form-control" type="file" class="upload" (change)="changeListener($event.target.files)">`

Answer (score 1):

If u want to make a file Null do this
`file= new File([],'');`
It will reinitialize the file object to an empty file object

Answer (score 0):

I've got no problem with this:

```
const file = files.item(0);
if (file && file !== null) {
  ...
```

and this:

```
const file: any = files.item(0);
if (file && file !== null) {
  ...
```

And even if I'm using `files[0]` instead of `files.item(0)`. And all this in `strict` mode.

Comment: Hi thanks I tried it and now it's giving this error,

`Object is possibly 'null'. <input class="form-control" type="file" class="upload" (change)="changeListener($event.target.files)">`

`Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. <input class="form-control" type="file" class="upload" (change)="changeListener($event.target.files)">`

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now I see another problem in your error: `Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'`. You can and you MUST solve that one before you can fix the `item(0)` thing. Maybe try `files: Event` instead of just `files` in the parameters section.